# How to work with child and dynamic routes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Using Nuxt2, I'm building a structure that I need dynamic routes.

This makes it necessary for navigation with more information.

Route: /lab/1/lad/2

Inside the route(page) lab I have two files, index.vue and a _id.vue

Inside the side learning to do the same, but including only the _id.vue

```
pages
--| lab/
-----| index.vue
-----| _id.vue
-----| lad/
--------| _id.vue
```

Page not found.

Could anyone help with this question?

Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nuxt2, try to make the `_id` as directory and add its own `index.vue` :

```
pages
--| lab/
-----| index.vue
-----| _id/
--------| index.vue
--------| lad/
-----------| _id.vue
```

Comment: Very Good. Thank you.